# Aggregate 15 min data to 1 hour data based on another column in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I got the following dataframe as an example using pandas:

| Timestamp | Computer no. | Memory Usage in % |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 05-07-2022 08:00:00 | 1 | 25 |
| 05-07-2022 08:00:00 | 2 | 56 |
| 05-07-2022 08:00:00 | 3 | 34 |
| 05-07-2022 08:15:00 | 1 | 23 |
| 05-07-2022 08:15:00 | 2 | 63 |
| 05-07-2022 08:15:00 | 3 | 23 |
| 05-07-2022 08:30:00 | 1 | 26 |
| 05-07-2022 08:30:00 | 2 | 56 |
| 05-07-2022 08:30:00 | 3 | 32 |
| 05-07-2022 08:45:00 | 1 | 23 |
| 05-07-2022 08:45:00 | 2 | 15 |
| 05-07-2022 08:45:00 | 3 | 86 |
| 05-07-2022 09:00:00 | 1 | 43 |
| 05-07-2022 09:00:00 | 2 | 26 |
| 05-07-2022 09:00:00 | 3 | 21 |

I would like to aggregate the time from a 15 Minute intervall to 1 hour. But I have different Computer No. in the same dataset. Firstly how do I aggregate the time to 1 hour and secondly how do I do it for each computer seperatly?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you aggregate the `Memory Usage` column at an hourly level? Are you looking for the mean across all four 15-minute intervals?

Comment: yes, looking for mean value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the `hour` value from the timestamp and then `groupby`  -

```py
df['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp']).dt.hour
df.groupby(['hour', 'Computer no.']).agg('mean').reset_index()
```

**Output**

```
   hour  Computer no.  Memory Usage in %
0     8             1              24.25
1     8             2              47.50
2     8             3              43.75
3     9             1              43.00
4     9             2              26.00
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
df = df.set_index('Timestamp')

df1 = df[df['Computer no.']==1].resample('1H').mean()
df2 = df[df['Computer no.']==2].resample('1H').mean()
df3 = df[df['Computer no.']==3].resample('1H').mean()
```